# GWT code spliting

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I use MVP and I have common views interfaces for mobile and desktop. Then I implement the views interfaces once for the mobile and once for the desktop. I use deferred binding to replace the interface with the actual implementation of the class. Views are instantiated in a ClientFactory.

How can I do code splitting so that the all the views for mobile are contained in one file and all the view for desktop in another file?

Comment: Wait - if you are using deferred binding (based on some property value I assume?) to swap out views for mobile or desktop, you already are in different permutations - what needs to be split beyond that? Are you sure that the mobile permutation has the desktop classes in it at all? Have you looked at the SOYC report to see why it has that, if there is some other mistake in your setup?

Comment: You are correct I use deferred binding based on a property value but the SOYC report indicates that only common permutations for desktop, tablet, mobile are generated! One large file contains all code. **Permutation 0 ('formfactor' : 'desktop' , 'user.agent' : 'gecko1_8') ('formfactor' : 'mobile' , 'user.agent' : 'gecko1_8') ('formfactor' : 'tablet' , 'user.agent' : 'gecko1_8')** HOW CAN I CHANGE THIS AND HAVE DIFFERENT PERMUTATIONS FOR MOBILE AND DESKTOP?

Comment: To answer that, you'll need to post the module itself - the details that describe how you have created the permutations and collapsed them in that way. Please post the `.gwt.xml` file for your app - there may be more than one, but it is important to see anything mentioning `formfactor` (though seeing other properties will help too).

Comment: Colin below you will find (as an answer) the .gwt.xml we use

Comment: Does anyone else have a clue of why the formfactor is not giving different permutations?

Comment: **SOLUTION:** in the formfactor.gwt.xml I commented out the line    **<collapse-property name="formfactor" values="*"/>** This forced the compiler to make different permutations for mobile and desktop.

Comment: That's the ticket, @EfstathiosKalyvas - I asked about posting more than one `.gwt.xml`, but was waiting to see the `FormFactor.gwt.xml` file to tell you what was in there, or what was referenced by _that_ file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the gwt.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  When updating your version of GWT, you should also update this DTD reference,
  so that your app can take advantage of the latest GWT module capabilities.
-->
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.0//EN"
  "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='apllo'>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.resources.Resources" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.Debug"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.activity.Activity"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.place.Place"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.http.HTTP"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.visualization.Visualization"/>

    <inherits name='com.apllo.client.FormFactor'/>

    <entry-point class='com.apllo.client.Apllo'/>


    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
    <source path='client'/>
    <source path='shared'/>
    <!-- Specify public paths -->
    <public path="files"/>

    <!-- Use ClientFactoryImpl by default -->
    <replace-with class="com.apllo.client.factory.ClientFactoryImpl"> 
        <when-type-is class="com.apllo.client.factory.ClientFactory"/>
    </replace-with>

    <!-- Use ClientFactoryImplMobile for mobile form factor. -->
    <replace-with class="com.apllo.client.factory.ClientFactoryMobileImpl">
      <when-type-is class="com.apllo.client.factory.ClientFactory"/>
      <when-property-is name="formfactor" value="mobile"/>
    </replace-with>

    <!-- 1.Use HeaderViewImpl by default -->
    <replace-with class="com.apllo.client.view.computer.HeaderViewImpl"> 
        <when-type-is class="com.apllo.client.view.HeaderView"/>
    </replace-with>
    <replace-with class="com.apllo.client.view.mobile.HeaderMobileViewImpl"> 
        <when-type-is class="com.apllo.client.view.HeaderView"/>
        <when-property-is name="formfactor" value="mobile"/>
    </replace-with>
    <!-- 2 -->
    <replace-with class="com.apllo.client.view.computer.StatusViewImpl"> 
        <when-type-is class="com.apllo.client.view.StatusView"/>
    </replace-with>
    <replace-with class="com.apllo.client.view.mobile.StatusMobileViewImpl"> 
        <when-type-is class="com.apllo.client.view.StatusView"/>
        <when-property-is name="formfactor" value="mobile"/>
    </replace-with>
    <!-- 3 -->
    <replace-with class="com.apllo.client.view.computer.PublicViewImpl"> 
        <when-type-is class="com.apllo.client.view.PublicView"/>
    </replace-with>
    <replace-with class="com.apllo.client.view.mobile.PublicMobileViewImpl"> 
        <when-type-is class="com.apllo.client.view.PublicView"/>
        <when-property-is name="formfactor" value="mobile"/>
    </replace-with>

    <!-- 4 -->
    <replace-with class="com.apllo.client.view.computer.MessageViewImpl"> 
        <when-type-is class="com.apllo.client.view.MessageView"/>
    </replace-with>
    <replace-with class="com.apllo.client.view.mobile.MessageMobileViewImpl"> 
        <when-type-is class="com.apllo.client.view.MessageView"/>
        <when-property-is name="formfactor" value="mobile"/>
    </replace-with>     

    <!-- 5 -->
    <replace-with class="com.apllo.client.view.computer.ContactsViewImpl"> 
        <when-type-is class="com.apllo.client.view.ContactsView"/>
    </replace-with>


    <!-- 6 -->
    <replace-with class="com.apllo.client.view.computer.AdvertisementViewImpl"> 
        <when-type-is class="com.apllo.client.view.AdvertisementView"/>
    </replace-with>


    <!-- 7 -->
    <replace-with class="com.apllo.client.view.computer.NewEditAdViewImpl"> 
        <when-type-is class="com.apllo.client.view.NewEditAdView"/>
    </replace-with>


    <!-- 8 -->
    <replace-with class="com.apllo.client.view.computer.AccountViewImpl"> 
        <when-type-is class="com.apllo.client.view.AccountView"/>
    </replace-with>
    <replace-with class="com.apllo.client.view.mobile.AccountMobileViewImpl"> 
        <when-type-is class="com.apllo.client.view.AccountView"/>
        <when-property-is name="formfactor" value="mobile"/>
    </replace-with> 


    <!-- 9 -->
    <replace-with class="com.apllo.client.view.computer.UtilityViewImpl"> 
        <when-type-is class="com.apllo.client.view.UtilityView"/>
    </replace-with>

</module>
```

Comment: SOLUTION: in the formfactor.gwt.xml I commented out the line <collapse-property name="formfactor" values="*"/> This forced the compiler to make different permutations for mobile and desktop.